# Impresso direto em Java

Tags: java, impressão, jasper-reports

Preciso criar um impresso para que saia em uma impressora térmica(não fiscal), no caso pensei em criar um impresso pelo JasperReports porém o Jasper busca no banco as informações e queria pegar as informações direto do meu sistema antes de enviar ao banco de dados, assim acho que economizo tempo no processo e economizo tempo no usuário ter que gravar e depois imprimir.
Existe algo em que posso me basear para criar este impresso.

Comment: só para te ajudar nesta busca de informações o Jasper pode sim buscar informações diretamente do banco de dados mas você também pode passar para ele a partir do java uma lista de objetos e parâmetros para ele preencher o relatório sem precisar se conectar na base de dados.

Comment: @FlavioAndrade Você teria um exemplo de algum impresso em que posso me espelhar e poder criar o que necessito? Só mais uma informação consigo também retirar o preview que o Jasper abre ao extrair um relatório, caso sim como poderei manipular a impressora que desejo imprimir?

Comment: [Aqui um exemplo](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/tutorial-criando-relatorios-com-jasperreports-primeiros-passos) de como passar uma lista de objetos do Java para o Jasper. Verifique se é isso que você precisa. Agora retirar o preview eu não sei dizer, nunca precisei fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu usei outra forma de realizar o impresso, de forma direta e e sem precisar ter que armazenar os dados no banco de dados e depois busca-los, sendo que é possível fazer a passagem de parâmetros por meio de um HashMap.

Para quem precisar de informações procure pela classe java.awt.print.PrinterJob
que será muito útil.